# Is Random Forest a special case of AdaBoost?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, decision-tree, adaboost

What is the difference if we use Decision Tree as Base estimator in AdaBoost algorithm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Random Forest a special case of AdaBoost?

Most certainly not; Random Forest is a case of *bagging* ensemble algorithm (short for [bootstrap aggregating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating)), which is different from boosting - check [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18891/bagging-boosting-and-stacking-in-machine-learning) for their differences.

> What is the difference if we use Decision Tree as Base estimator in AdaBoost algorithm ?

You don't get a Random Forest, but a [Gradient Tree Boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting#Gradient_tree_boosting) Machine, available in several packages like [xgboost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (R/Python), [gbm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/index.html) (R), [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html) (Python) etc.

Check chapter 8 of the excellent (and freely available) book [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) for more, or [The Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/) (heavy in math & theory, not for the faint-hearted)...